# Long tasks in Application class

Tags: android

Is it a good practice to make long tasks such as server requests in the application class? Let's say these requests are for initialization,is it still fine to place these requests in the oncreate method in the Application class.

Comment: No its not a good practice.

Comment: No! Why? Because depending on the model of your phone or you are going to see a white screen for seconds or you tap on the app icon and seemingly nothing will happen.

Comment: Thank you for the answers...I just wanted to get a valid answer after arguing with a co-worker.

Answer (score 2):

It is not. Everything inside the onCreate of Application class will be executed in the main thread, resulting in freezing the UI if your task takes a lot of time.

The best practice, when it comes to operations such as communicating witha server, is to implement a Repository Pattern and execute the time consuming operations in a different thread, then use the results in the UI Thread.

Comment: Thank you a lot my friend just as I thought, as i commented above I was asking this newbi question after arguing with a co-worker.